# Insert image when Input selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want that when i choose **input selected option**, to display my desire image above it, in a DIV.

See Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/7qkmg/

See Image example here (Unselected): http://oi60.tinypic.com/2isiohi.jpg

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
    <td width="200">
        <label for="select-song">Select your favourite song</label>
    </td>
    <td width="200">            
        <label for="select-gender">Select gender</label>
    </td>
    <td width="100">
        <label for="your-mood">Your mood</label>
    </td>
    <td width="100"> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="song" id="select-song" class="input-step">
            <option value="">Select song</option>
            <option value="Katyusha">Katyusha</option>
            <option value="Gangnam style">Gangnam style</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>            
        <select name="gender" id="select-gender" class="input-step">
            <option>Select gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
         <select name="gender" id="select-gender" class="input-step">
            <option>Select gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: image will come dynamically or just hidden and you want to show it

Comment: Where's the `<DIV>` in which you want to display the desired image?

Comment: shouldn't you try a little javascript?

Comment: It can be hidden. i will put the div later. If i knew JS i was put inside :)

Comment: @StackBuck: please post a fiddle link with your html and jQuery code

Comment: @Devima Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/353uJ/2/

Comment: @StackBuck: your fiddle does not work because in script you have forgot to insert on document.ready event in the script, check my previous answer i pas to you real code without fiddle. If you like it remeber vote me;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple example with only one options to give you an idea
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/6DnZE/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select-song').on('change',function(){
        $('#show img').remove()
        var img=$('option:selected').val()
        $('<img>').attr('src',img).appendTo('#show')
        })

})
</script>
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.
I pass you all code
this is a working online page link: http://www.videmadesign.herobo.com/stak1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
    display: none;
    }

    table {
        border: 1px dashed #999;
    }

    table td {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px dashed #999;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--in fiddle you have select domready event from sx tabs but you have no insert in the script-->
    <!--if you put the script in the javascript section of fiddle page you can not insert domready event in the script-->
    <!--but if you put the script in html section of fiddle page you have to insert domready event in the script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*document ready event you forgot*/
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select-song').on('change',function(){
            $('#show img').remove()
            var img=$('option:selected').val()
            $('<img>').attr('src',img).appendTo('#show')
        })
    })
    </script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <table width="600">
        <tr>
            <td width="200">
                <label for="select-song">Select your favourite song</label>
            </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="song" id="select-song" class="input-step">
                    <option value=""></option> 
                  <option value="http://s25.postimg.org/5fhbardwb/mini_botti.jpg">aaa</option>
                  <option value="http://s25.postimg.org/3oya99wd7/mini_topo.jpg">bbb</option>
                  <option value="http://s25.postimg.org/3u0pkd1cr/minigatto.jpg">ccc</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="show"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really dont know why, but in JSfiddle it works but in my html page it wont. Maybe the problem is somthing belongs to onDomready

Comment: OK. Now it works, But, i change the location of the div, and the images stays in the same place- under the input and not above it. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/353uJ/3/

Comment: @StackBuck the images are inserted in #show div if this div is before yoyr table(as in your last fiddle page) the images will appear before table. So you have to put #show div after table in your html. in my post there is a link for a online page(and this page works very well) you can copy the code of that page and.. please vote me up, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I can think of a few suggestions:

1) Add an empty img tag with an id in each of the table cells you'd like the image to appear. So for example, in the "Select your mood" cell, change to the following:

```
<td width="100">
    <label for="your-mood">Your mood</label>
    <img id="mood" src="" />
</td>
```

2) Add some jquery code where you add an event to the select list, isolate which option is selected, and append an image to the div in the table cell. Something along the lines of this:

```
$('#select-mood').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('#mood).attr('src') = selected + '.jpg';
});
```